# Can we use fermionic modes as qubits?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, hilbert-space, fermions

They both are two state systems, the only difference being the exchange statistics.

Answer (score 1):

There is a classic work by Bravyi and Kitaev that shows how one can embed $m$ number of qubits into fermionic modes such that any unitary acting on the $m$ quits can be represented in an easy way as a unitary on the fermionic system. Here is a link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0003137.pdf . (And also the parity super-selection rule is respected in this scheme.)

Comment: Yeah. I have come across the mentioned work on representing the gates using fermionic operators. The absence of a direct tensor product structure was tackled by using extra overhead operators when implementing the gates of the Hilbert space in the fermionic foch space. Is it not?

Comment: @ApremPJoy Yes, basically that is how they do it.

Comment: @ApremPJoy Did then this Bravyi-Kitaev method basically answer you question?

Comment: Yeah, it is a very general and sound framework. But I wanted to know more about quasi-particles(fermionic) in many body systems whose foch spacesare not defined straight forward(ie, most often, operators defined on the many body system creates/destroys such particles).

Answer (score -1):

Sure, that might be hard to implement in practice, but in principle any two-level system works.

One issue would be that it's difficult to physically implement operators that violate fermion parity, so "$\sigma^x$" gates like $a + a^\dagger$ would be difficult to implement. But you could in principle implement them in an open system by hopping fermions in and out out of the system.

Another issue is that if you had multiple qubits, then you'd probably want to keep them well-separated, so that you could neglect the antisymmetrization requirement and effectively work with the full tensor-product Hilbert space. In this case it could be quite tricky to entangle the faraway qubits together in practice.

Comment: Thank you. In that respect, would it be possible to implement universal gates using local fermionic modes (quasiparticles) and their phase acquisition during exchange? For example, in several many body systems, the quasiparticle excitations are fermionic. PS. I am not talking about Majorana fermions.

Comment: @ApremPJoy Anything you can do with "real" fermions you can do with fermionic quasiparticles. But I don't think you can do much useful computation just by physically exchanging them and using the acquired phase factors. That's because the acquired phase factors are abelian, and you need nonabelian exchange statistics for universal quantum computation. For a useful computation I think you'd need to be able to create and remove fermions in a controlled way, not just exchange them.

Comment: @tparker They're not difficult to implement, they're impossible to implement.  If you do it using an open system, you add a fermion *incoherently*.  This is not what you want.  For QC with fermions, you have to use subspaces with fixed number of fermions.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thank you. Could you please explain what you exactly mean by adding fermions coherently?. Also, what if the many body system allows creation and destruction of fermionic excitations, like in the Toric code.

Comment: @ApremPJoy I guess I was inaccurate: What you need is operations which allow you to create superpositions of different fermion numbers, which is impossible. Just adding a fermion is in principle possible (contrary to what I said above), but also pretty much useless (especially for fermions).  Note that adding a fermion to a mode is also non-unitary (if it is occupied it will be annihilated.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I dont quite understand why states with different fermion numbers cant be superposed. Could you suggest me some literature on that? For instance, if $\sigma^x |0> = |1>$, wouldn't an operation $e^{(-i\sigma^x\theta)}$ result in a superposition?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch In a superconductor you have a coherent state superposition of different numbers of electrons (bound in Cooper pairs).

Comment: @tparker That's not true - it's a convenient simplification.  The only way to make sense (=measure) that is to have TWO superconductors which are coupled. Same as for lasers: The coherent state with a fixed phase is just a convenient illusion, it only makes sense once you interfere two coupled lasers.  The TOTAL state of the system is an incoherent mixture.   Regardless of that, you don't have a superposition of different fermionic PARITIES, which is what would matter for qubits.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree that Hamiltonians that violate fermion parity would be very difficult (and probably impossible) to engineer in practice, but I'm inclined to be conservative and not state definitively that it is completely impossible. Certain exotic theories ([here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269301007857) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037026930101293X)) allow for the possibility of fermion parity violation.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch E.g. [this article](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.033102) says that "It is an open question whether this [fermion-parity-violating] realization has a role in physical
theory. We note that, within supersymmetry, fermion parity
violation is a recognized and accepted phenomenon."

Comment: Please refer to my last comment. The kind of operations i wrote are typical in a Toric code like system, where |1}, refers to an excitation bring present at a site and |0} for no excitation. So it does seem that it allows superpositions.

Comment: Anyway, this whole debate is fairly irrelevant to the OP's question, because I was actually thinking of hopping the fermions into ancilla states over which you can maintain quantum coherence, not into an external environment you can't control, very similarly to the proposal in other answer. In this case there's certainly no problem, because not only fermion parity but actual fermion number is conserved. I should have clarified that by "system" I was only referring to the computational qubits, and by "open system" I meant that they were coupled (coherently) to non-computational ancilla qubits.

Comment: @tparker In that case, the simplest solution is to just use one fermion in a (deep) double well potential.  Left=|0>, Right=|1>.